# Installers created with the Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS) are recognized as Malware by Windows Defender

Tags: nsis

I created an installation package with NSIS and distributed it to others.

Windows Defender (used in Windows 10) is recognized as malware and will not download.

Detect malware: trojan (Win32 / Fuerboos.A! Cl)

Why is Malware recognized when there are no files infected with viruses or malware in the installation package?

Not long ago there was no problem, it occurred recently.

The only solution is to turn off Windows Defender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens from time to time. You can report a false-positive [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line "unicode True" in your code.